What is the first recorded use of the conditional form in human history?
The conditional form, ⟨ IF ϕ, THEN ψ ⟩, seems to have always been with us, but we don't really know.
So, what is the first attested use of the conditional form in human history?
Thank you for any scholarly reference.

Code of Hammurabi?

The Instructions of Shuruppak and the Code of Urukagina are even older than the Code of Hammurabi, and though only a little of those texts has survived, they seem to have contained conditionals. A code of laws is almost bound to contain conditionals. There are conditionals in the Egyptian Book of the Dead and the Biblical Book of Job both of which are of unknown date.

(1) It's not completely clear what you mean by "the conditional form" (also see my replies to your further questioning): Is it just the syntax construction of conditional, or is it be the conditional as explicitly used in logic - so the conditional in the context of deductive reasoning or argumentation? (Or yet something else?)
(2) I'm genuinely curious to know what you hope to get from the answers to your question (in either interpretation in (1) or in yet another interpretation). What will any answer tell you?

@mudskipper "* Is it just the syntax construction of conditional, or is it be the conditional as explicitly used in logic - so the conditional in the context of deductive reasoning or argumentation?*" There is only one conditional. Although there are different forms, you can translate all forms into the IF-THEN structure. The so-called "material conditional" used in some mathematical contexts is not a conditional despite the name.

@mudskipper "What will any answer tell you?" Sorry, this is classified, but something very interesting, hopefully!

The Sumeric artifacts are earlier, but some of the oracle bone inscriptions of the late Shang Dynasty (1200-1046 BCE) contain conditionals. One example is mentioned in the wikipedia entry:

戊寅卜旅貞王其于[阝心] 亡災


Prognostication on the day wuyin by Diviner Lü: if the king travels to [placename, possibly read Xin], will there be harm?

Note that in early Chinese the conditional is often expressed, as here, by simple juxtaposition: "p  q" rather than "if p then q". It's still completely unambiguous based on the grammatical structure and context that we're dealing with a conditional construction.
It's hard to imagine any natural language that didn't have some way to express conditionals. One reason why this is hard to imagine is that there are also clear pre-linguistic conditionals in non-verbal communication. (E.g. pavlovian conditioning; or pointing - as signal to another primate that one wants something.) To understand language -- to understand how logic works and how meaning is acquired --, it's necessary to also consider the pragmatics of speech acts and the non-linguistic embedding of language in pre-verbal communication.

It is said of the human brain that it at least has the computational ability of the Turing Machine, and essential to the TM are exactly three processes: processing a symbol (operation), deciding among symbols (conditional), and recursing through symbols (iteration). If this is the case, then the external manifestation of the conditional in language is an inevitable consequence of the very ability of neurons themselves to calculate whether to fire or not. IF-THEN is the outward manifestation of action potential.

@mudskipper "the conditional is often expressed, as here, by simple juxtaposition" Can you tell where the juxtaposition is? A prediction doesn't necessarily requires a conditional. So, how do we know that there is a conditional in this case?

With juxtaposition I just meant that 'q' follows 'p' in the "p, q" sentence. It's a question of grammar. Leaving out the explicit "then" (or "if .. then") word is similar to for instance the lack of an explicit copula in Russian. Literally in Russian, you say "Эта лошадь белая" (eta lohsyadj bjehlaya) ("this horse white"), which means "This horse is white". So in English we have to use an explicit "is".  In classical Chinese, the conditional can also be explicitly expressed (p 則 q = "p thus q" = "if p then q") but usually, if the meaning is clear from context, explicit connectives are absent.

(Note that an interpretative step is also required in English when someone says "if p then q", since in English this could -- depending on semantic context -- also either be meant as logical conditional, or as causal conditional, or simply as temporal sequence. In some contexts it may be clear however that it's really meant as a purely logical connective. Similar in classical Chinese.)

@Speakpigeon - A prediction ("if p happens then q will happen") expresses a causal or (at least) temporal relation, but this can also be seen as a logical relation when we want to use that prediction in (deductive) reasonings. So, imo, what "makes" a relation into a "logical" relation (or what constitues an interpretation as logical connective) depends both on conventional grammar, semantics and on the pragmatic context (deductive reasoning). (Sherlock Holmes stories would be imcomprehensible otherwise :) )

So, strictly speaking you could claim that the above is not an unambiguous example of logical "if ... then...".  I agree. (However, it's then also not unambigiously wrong to make that claim). But to find unambgious examples of a logical "if ... then..." would require finding a context where it's actually used in a deductive argument. Narrative contexts could then often be ambiguous. So, we'd need to have either mathematical, (proto)-scientific or philosophical/ethical contexts. But note that deductive arguments are also often not made completely explicit (even in modern philosophy).

Btw - For an examples with "p 則 q" (in a quasi-deductive context) see for instance: https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&id=1137 (Lunyu/The Analects - composed in 5th to 4th century BCE). Classical Chinese had other ways of expressing the conditional too (e.g. "p 而 q" (also plenty of examples in the Analects), but "而" in most contexts means simply "and" (often as contrastive "but").

@mudskipper 1. Conditionals always express a logical relation. - 2. "A prediction ("if p happens then q will happen")" Predictions are not necessarily conditional: 貞王 will die in 阝心. 3. "what "makes" a relation into a "logical" relation" This is what I'm asking: How do we know the prediction is conditional in this particular case since there is no conditional expression in it?

How do we know the Russian sentence is a complete predicative sentence, since there is no copula in it? It's a grammatical, syntagmatic pattern. Same in Chinese.

@mudskipper "to find unambgious examples of a logical "if ... then" The conditional seems to require a specific form, with key words like IF-THEN, to avoid terminal ambiguity. If the Chinese used conditionals at the time, they must have had a specific form with key words for it, like they do today.

"If we will make a fire, there will be smoke visible in the distance" Does this according to you use a conditional? It is indeed possible to interpret "the king will goto Xin, disaster will happen" as two unconnected facts, but obviously that is not the the appropriate contextual interpretation, since in the pragmatic context of oracle use, the question is always "What will happen if ... ?"

@mudskipper "Narrative contexts could then often be ambiguous." Yes, and this is why we need a specific form and key words, whatever they are.

What you are saying is clearly incorrect from a linguistic point of view, but you are welcome to stick to your opinions.

If you are talking about the use of the conditional in general, it would be hard to imagine a natural language without the use of conditional; but I suppose one can argue that without a historical record, there may have been natural languages without the notion of if and then. I also suppose definitive proof of the use of if and then might be found in the West in the Epic of Gilgamesh, a Mesopotamian epic. From WP:
EDIT
Pursuant to comments, the Kesh Temple Hymn and the Instructions of Shuruppak are certainly older.

The Epic of Gilgamesh (/ˈɡɪlɡəmɛʃ/)4 is an epic from ancient Mesopotamia. The literary history of Gilgamesh begins with five Sumerian poems about Gilgamesh (formerly read as Sumerian "Bilgames"4), king of Uruk, some of which may date back to the Third Dynasty of Ur (c. 2100 BC).1 These independent stories were later used as source material for a combined epic in Akkadian.

While I personally can't read Sumerian, a quick search will show there are a number of conditional statements in the translation, so presumably Sumerians had a construct for if-then. That's evidence from 5,000 years ago. However, it seems like the use of the conditional is baked into all human metaphysical thought. In The Logical Basis of Metaphysics by Michael Dummett on page 170 begins on talking about the metaphysical basis of the conditional:

A great part of what we take as belonging to the intuitive notion of truth derives from the perceived need for distinguishing truth from the existence of evidence... still less are we aware that it is motivated by a disposition to prefer a notion of truth that distributes over disjunction and the conditional to one that does not... It is the behavior of sentences when they figure as antecedents of conditionals that most powerfully influences what we take to be the 'intuitive' conception of truth. What most vividly testifies to this is our uncertainty about how to apply the notion of truth to conditionals themselves, that is, to the indicative conditionals of natural language.

One can take this as that the use of disjunction and implication in natural language is a reflection of our intuitive understanding that there are possibilities in the world. The conditional then is just the language we use to help describe these possibilities. As noted above by Dummett, the conditional serves the purpose of housing a basic theory that differentiates the evidence in the antecedent from the logical truth value of the conclusion in the consequent.
In logic, of course, Aristotle and his syllogism is a major milestone in the history of the use of conditional. Prior Analytics and eventually the work of the Stoics helped establish the Greeks of Antiquity as the first systematic logicians, and modern symbolic logic and the use of the conditional is frequently attributed to Frege.

"the Epic of Gilgamesh" I would expect any story to include a fair share of conditionals. I was thinking of more prosaic and more ancient texts.  - 2. "modern symbolic logic . . . is frequently attributed to Frege." How does this contribute to answering the question? - 3. ". . . the use of the conditional is frequently attributed to Frege." Are you serious?!


Well, after 10 minutes of poking around, all I could find was Kesh temple humn and the Instructions of Shuruppak. The latter would seem likely to contain the use of the conditional? 2. It was just a passing fact for third parties interested in the history of the conditional. 3. You misquoted: "modern symbolic logic AND the use of the conditional". If I said "mom and dad had a baby", it would be odd to quote: "dad had a baby". You've done the same.


@Corbin I find it fascinating you feel the need to impose your views on others. What's the source of this motivation? Overbearing parents? Overcompensation for inadequacy? God's plan?

@JD Thanks for the Dummett quote - It's a very nice, sharp observation Dummett makes there. It must also be related, I think, to the 'intuitive' appeal of correspondence theories of truth.

@mudskipper It's all related! But yes, rationalism, logical coherence, and the correspondence theory of truth are tightly entwined. The how of that in philosophy of language seems to be at the intersection of assertoric force, linguistic context, and logical contradiction. See this paper by Mark Jary. Fascinating stuff.

@JD: If you don't know my motivation, then you shouldn't guess~

@JD - I have great admiration for Dummett (and am really attracted to intuitionism), but I find the last sentence of the quote extremely problematic. The way implication is defined in the prop. calculus in formal logic makes sense, but it's strongly counter-intuitive -- as almost any honest person will admit -- it's based on a technicality (an important one, but even so "just" a technicality) to define "p->q" as true when "p" is false. So, imo this has nothing to do with a more basic intuition of truth.

@mudskipper Are you conflating material and indicative conditional? Because Dummett's quote refers to the latter, and you are talking about the former.

@JD - I was indeed talking about the material conditional. But the way I read the last sentence (perhaps I'm misreading it?!) is that Dummett also implicitly refers to those. Why else is he speaking of uncertainties?  The uncertainty in interpretation I took to be the tension between material and indicative conditionals. But I don't find anything uncertain about how to apply truth in indicative conditionals... (it's trivial in fact). So?

@JD - How do you read the last sentence? Is Dummett simply referring to the "uncertainty" of applying a general rule (going from evidence to preceding cause for instance; or from cause to following effect)? I guess, without more context I don't quite understand that quote.

@mudskipper Ah, I see. I read the uncertainty as rejecting the material as a type of indicative conditional as an accurate model of cognition leaving one to choose an alternative explanation. If we set aside the Boolean, mathematical interpretation, which fails because of non-intuitiveness, then should we instead accept some sort of criterion of relevance, probability, possibility, or linguistic context as the basis of our truth conditions instead? Perhaps a pluralist interpretation of inference in thought? And if we reject classical logic as supplying those truth conditions, then what?

@mudskipper Thus, outside of the narrow box of Tarskian truth-conditional semantics with its reliance on the material conditional as a facsimile of reason, we have to confront the messy nature of how our intuitive notion of truth is like polysemous and relies on pluralist criteria of truth definition, multiple theories of truth, and non-classical applications of truth. Of course, like I said, I don't have the passage handy at the moment, and would have to reread to establish a broader context.

If what is known as the oldest profession is indeed the oldest, then "if ... then ..." conditionals are as old as history itself: if ... then I'll give you a goat".  Instances of this are recorded in the scripture (Genesis 38:17-18).

Please give a more precise citation.

Most of the Bible was allegedly written 3rd to 7th centrury AD IIRC

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_F._Albright dated Jacob to 19th century BCE. @Phil

May well be I'm remembering dating of texts of the New Testament, cheers for the input

If you're talking about the New Testament, then the letters of Paul date back to just a few years after Jesus' execution (Galatians, ca 48 AD). The Torah dates back to around 4th century BCE according to contemporary bible scholars. The Nevi'im (Prophets) probably got their form between 8th and 5th centuries BCE.

@Corbin - https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Genesis-Chapter-38/

So, the suggestion here seems to be that all bargaining is based on conditionals ("if you do this, then I will do that"). But pointing seems a more primitive act than bargaining - and all pointing also seems based on a grasp of conditionals (if you look there, you will find what you want; if I do this, then I expect you to do that) - In that case, it seems clear that other primates also have an understanding of conditionals. -- As Wittgenstein points out in the Tractatus: All logical constants are always implied in each statement (proposition). I would add commands. "Look there!".
